# Long Table extended cross the paper margin

Tags: tables, margins, longtable

I am trying to insert a long word table on the appendix page, the table includes over 40 questions for the survey. However, I received something like this, screenshot below:
[image]

[image]

the code is something like this:
{the table is way too long, I split table in multiple pages, and repeat header on every page and wish to keep for this way}

```
\begin{longtable}[c]{ccl}\hline 
Item & Questionnaire Items & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Questionnaire \\ Contents\end{tabular}} \\ \hline \endfirsthead
\multicolumn{3}{c}{{\bfseries Table \thetable\ continued from previous page}} \\ \hline Item & Questionnaire Items & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Questionnaire \\ Contents\end{tabular}} \\ \hline \endhead
\hline \endfoot \endlastfoot
Self-Efficacy & SE1 & To what extend do you feel comfortable with online learning environments during the COVID-19 pandemic period? \\
 & SE2 & How comfortable are you in using learning management platform? (e.g. Moodle, Canvas, Blackboard, etc.)? \\
& SE3 & Please rate the effectiveness of your learning when using e-learning system during the COVID-19 pandemic. \\
& SE4 & I believe that I can achieve my learning goals using online learning environments effectively. \\
& SE5 & My self-efficacy in online learning positively impacts my motivation to participate actively in courses. \\
Anxiety & AX1 & Working on a computer during the lockdown makes me feel uncomfortable and stressed. \\
    & AX2 & I experience feelings of anxiety and stress while using the online learning system during the lockdown. \\
    & AX3 & I find it challenging to cope with the demands of technology usage during the lockdown. \\
    & AX4 & I feel confident and at ease when operating computer-based tools and applications during the lockdown. \\
    & AX5 & The use of digital devices and online platforms adds to my overall stress levels during the lockdown. \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `{ccl}` is three columns that do not allow linebreaks, try `{llp{7cm}}` so last column wraps to that width

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.Se!

Since relevant part of your document preamble is unknow, I use `article` document class and in MWE (Minimal Working Example) add needed package for compilation of your table. So, it ma happen, that in your real document table will looks a bit differently.

With use `xltabular`, `ragged2e` and `makecell` packages instead of the `longtable` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage{xltabular}

\begin{document}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{l  c  >{\RaggedRight}X}
    \toprule
Item    &   \makecell{Questionnaire\\ Items}
                &   \makecell{Questionnaire\\ Contents}          \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
    \toprule
Item    &   \makecell{Questionnaire\\ Items}
                &   \makecell{Questionnaire\\ Contents}          \\
    \midrule
\endhead
    \bottomrule
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
Self-Efficacy
        & SE1   &   To what extend do you feel comfortable with online learning environments during the COVID-19 pandemic period?
                    \\
        & SE2   &   How comfortable are you in using learning management platform? (e.g. Moodle, Canvas, Blackboard, etc.)?
                    \\
        & SE3   &   Please rate the effectiveness of your learning when using e-learning system during the COVID-19 pandemic.
                    \\
        & SE4   &   I believe that I can achieve my learning goals using online learning environments effectively.
                    \\
        & SE5   &   My self-efficacy in online learning positively impacts my motivation to participate actively in courses.
                    \\
    \addlinespace
Anxiety & AX1   &    Working on a computer during the lockdown makes me feel uncomfortable and stressed.
                    \\
        & AX2   &   I experience feelings of anxiety and stress while using the online learning system during the lockdown.
                    \\
        & AX3   &   I find it challenging to cope with the demands of technology usage during the lockdown.
                    \\
        & AX4   &   I feel confident and at ease when operating computer-based tools and applications during the lockdown.
                    \\
        & AX5   & The use of digital devices and online platforms adds to my overall stress levels during the lockdown.
                    \\
% copy, that table is longer than one page
    \addlinespace
Anxiety & AX1   &    Working on a computer during the lockdown makes me feel uncomfortable and stressed.
                    \\
        & AX2   &   I experience feelings of anxiety and stress while using the online learning system during the lockdown.
                    \\
        & AX3   &   I find it challenging to cope with the demands of technology usage during the lockdown.
                    \\
        & AX4   &   I feel confident and at ease when operating computer-based tools and applications during the lockdown.
                    \\
        & AX5   & The use of digital devices and online platforms adds to my overall stress levels during the lockdown.
                    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or by use of the `tabularray` and ˙ragged2e` packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath, booktabs}
\SetTblrStyle{contfoot}{font=\footnotesize\itshape}
\SetTblrStyle{note}{font=\small}


\begin{document}
\begingroup
\DefTblrTemplate{capcont}{default}{}
\begin{longtblr}[
    entry=none,     % <---
    label=none,     % <---
                ]{colspec = { Q[l]  Q[c] X[cmd=\RaggedRight] },
                  row{1}  = {m},
                  rowhead = 1
                  }
% column headers
    \toprule
Item    &   {Questionnaire\\ Items} 
                &   Questionnaire Contents          \\
    \midrule
Self-Efficacy 
        & SE1   &   To what extend do you feel comfortable with online learning environments during the COVID-19 pandemic period?                   
                    \\
        & SE2   &   How comfortable are you in using learning management platform? (e.g. Moodle, Canvas, Blackboard, etc.)?                          
                    \\
        & SE3   &   Please rate the effectiveness of your learning when using e-learning system during the COVID-19 pandemic.                          
                    \\
        & SE4   &   I believe that I can achieve my learning goals using online learning environments effectively.                               
                    \\
        & SE5   &   My self-efficacy in online learning positively impacts my motivation to participate actively in courses.                        
                    \\
    \addlinespace
Anxiety & AX1   &    Working on a computer during the lockdown makes me feel uncomfortable and stressed. 
                    \\
        & AX2   &   I experience feelings of anxiety and stress while using the online learning system during the lockdown.                               
                    \\
        & AX3   &   I find it challenging to cope with the demands of technology usage during the lockdown. 
                    \\
        & AX4   &   I feel confident and at ease when operating computer-based tools and applications during the lockdown. 
                    \\
        & AX5   & The use of digital devices and online platforms adds to my overall stress levels during the lockdown. 
                    \\
% copy, that table is longer than one page
    \addlinespace
Anxiety & AX1   &    Working on a computer during the lockdown makes me feel uncomfortable and stressed.
                    \\
        & AX2   &   I experience feelings of anxiety and stress while using the online learning system during the lockdown.
                    \\
        & AX3   &   I find it challenging to cope with the demands of technology usage during the lockdown.
                    \\
        & AX4   &   I feel confident and at ease when operating computer-based tools and applications during the lockdown.
                    \\
        & AX5   & The use of digital devices and online platforms adds to my overall stress levels during the lockdown.
                    \\
    \bottomrule
   \end{longtblr}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

- In both cases are for table horizontal lines used rules defined in the `booktabs` package.
- In the second example the table is (to my taste) a bit nicer, code is simpler, but for compilation it take a wee bit more time.

Comment: You should edit your question and extend your code fragment to complete small document. Anyway, does my answer solve your problem? If yes, please consider to accept it (by clicking on checkmark at top left side of answer).

Comment: Thank you for your response to my question. This is my first time using LaTeX to write a master's thesis, and I decided to use the University of Waterloo master thesis template for the layout and format [link](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/university-of-waterloo-thesis-template-updated-august-2022/qxqqzmbrcmpp). I truly appreciate your assistance and the answers you provided. However, it seems that the solutions you offered do not entirely align with my template. Would you be able to access the template link and take a look at my document preamble? Thank you so much

Comment: @Rurri, in what sense my answer not align with your template? Of course, to it you need add preamble of my MWE.

Comment: I create a new file and try the code again. Sorry about the confusion and it totally work.